# Why is $\operatorname{U}(n,\mathbb{H})\subset \operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{H}) $?

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, quaternions

This question is inspired by [Maximal compact subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{H})$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195060/maximal-compact-subgroup-of-mathrmsl2-mathbbh). Consider the embedding $\operatorname{U}(n,\mathbb{H})\subset \operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{H})  $. Since $\operatorname{U}(n,\mathbb{H})\cong \operatorname{Sp}(n) $ is almost simple, we know that it is actually contained in $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{H})  $, the kernel of the Dieudonné determinant $\ \det: \operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{H})  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^*_{+}\,$. Is there a direct way to prove   $\det A=1$ for $A\in \operatorname{U}(n,\mathbb{H})  $?

(Recall that $\ \det\, {}^{t}\overline{A}\neq \det A\ $ for $A$ general in $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{H}) $.)

Comment: Does $\mathbb R^*_+$ mean the multiplicative group of positive real numbers?  Are you identifying it with the usual target of the Dieudonné determinant $\mathbb H^\times/[\mathbb H^\times, \mathbb H^\times]$ *via* the norm map?

Comment: @LSpice: Yes and yes. This is already in Dieudonné's original paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, relying on the fact that elements of the symplectic group (over $\mathbf{C}$, and hence over $\mathbf{R}$) have determinant 1.

Indeed, an element $g$ of $\mathrm{U}(n,\mathbf{H})$ preserves the canonical Hermitian form $b$. Let $b'$ be any imaginary component of $b$. Then $b'$ is a $g$-invariant real-valued symplectic form on the $4n$-dimensional real space $\mathbf{H}^n$. So the determinant of $g$ as $4n$-dimensional matrix (which is the Dieudonné determinant) is $1$.

**Edit** (abx): actually the determinant $\det_{\mathbb{R}}(g)$ of $g$ as a real $4n$-dimensional matrix is $(\det_{D}( g))^4$, where $\det_D$ is the Dieudonné determinant — since $\det_D(g)\in\mathbb{R}^*_+$, this implies $\det_D(g)=1$ as required.

Indeed $\det_{\mathbb{R}}$ is a homomorphism from  $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{H}) $ to $\mathbb{R}^*$; such a homomorphism is trivial on the derived subgroup  $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{H}) $. Since $\det_D$ induces an isomorphism of
$\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{H}) /\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{H}) $ onto $\mathbb{R}^*_+$, we have $\det_{\mathbb{R}}=\varphi \circ \det_{D}$, where $\varphi :\mathbb{R}^*_+\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^*$ is a continuous homomorphism. Such a homomorphism is of the form $x\mapsto x^{a}$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$; thus $\det_{\mathbb{R}}=  (\det_{D})^{a}$. Taking $g= tI_n$ gives $a=4$.

Comment: Is it clear that the determinant of $g$ as a real $4n$-dimensional matrix is the Dieudonné determinant?

Comment: @abx I actually thought it was the definition. I'll check. (Well, it might be the square instead?)

Comment: I would guess the fourth power — think of the multiplication by a real number. Of course that would be sufficient, since these determinants live in $\mathbb{R}^*_{+}$. But how does one prove it?

Comment: @abx if you know that the derived subalgebra of the real Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}_n(H)$ has codimension 1 and that $\mathrm{GL}_n(H)$ is Zariski-connected, then it should follow that the maps are multiplicatively proportional (on the set of real points).

Comment: Is there any way to prove this without looking at a set of generators?  At least, that's the only proof I know for symplectic matrices—look at what happens on the torus and root groups, and then observe that they generate the entire symplectic group.  I've always wondered about a more conceptual proof.

Comment: @YCor: Yes. In fact, you only need that $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{H}) $ is the derived subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{H}) $ — a fact which is relatively simple. I have taken the liberty to add an edit to your answer — correct me if you disagree.

Comment: @abx thanks for completing the answer!